# Remove null values in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

[image: id and languages descriptions]

Hello, Does anuone knows how can I remowe the null values corresponding to the description of the same product key? So, I have one product Key and its description in each language.

I'm trying to use the coalesce function, but it doesnt return me anything.

Comment: To avoid down votes, show us the SQL you tried and desired output. Include CREATE TABLE DDL and sample data INSERT statements instead of pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to combine the rows together for each ProductKey.

So instead of 5 lines, each with a single column populated, you want one line, with all 5 columns populated.

Do it like this:

```
Select Distinct T.ProductKey, C1.Column1, C2.Column2, C3.Column3 from MyTable T
left join MyTable C1 on C1.ProductKey = T.ProductKey and C1.Column1 is not null
left join MyTable C2 on C2.ProductKey = T.ProductKey and C2.Column2 is not null
left join MyTable C3 on C3.ProductKey = T.ProductKey and C3.Column3 is not null
```

Just replace "MyTable" above with your table name, and "Column1, Column2, Column3" with the names of the columns your data is in.

Pretend that each column is on its own separate table, and you need to use joins to connect all the tables back to your master set of ProductKeys.

Think about it in sets:
Basically you are going to make one master list of the keys that is distinct/unique (step 1), and then do a new left join for each column you want to attach to the master list (step 2), and as part of the joins, tell it to get the non-NULL values and ignore the NULLs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GROUP BY` as below.

```
SELECT ProductKey,
       MAX(C_ar_description) AS C_ar_description,
       MAX(C_en_description) AS C_en_description,
       MAX(C_fr_description) AS C_fr_description
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ProductKey
```

You should use the results to fix the data so you dont need to do this every time.